# How to find command line program with which

Tags: terminal, macos

I am trying to remove all traces of [Ureka](http://ssb.stsci.edu/ureka/1.0beta5/docs/uninstallation.html). I followed the instructions in the link to do this, but when I test if it is gone with `$ur_setup` I see that the terminal does know what it should be looking for, because it says:

```
-bash: /Users/myname/.ureka/ur_setup: No such file or directory
```

But when I type `$which ur_setup` nothing is returned. And I have deleted the directory in the above code with

```
rm -rf /Users/myname/code/Ureka
rm -rf $HOME/.ureka
rm -rf $HOME/.ureka_tmp
```

How can I delete all memory of this program so that terminal does not know where it should look for the program?

As a note, when I `$echo $PATH` I get:

```
/Users/myname/code:/Users/myname/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

Comment: Between removing Ureka and running `$ur_setup`, did you restart terminal? If not the variable would be in memory…

Comment: Also, might be worth checking it’s not set in your shells rc file (probably ~/.bashrc or maybe ~/.profile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You removed the application according to the documentation. Now unset the variable ur_setup

```
    unset ur_setup
```

You are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in `echo $PATH | sed 's/:/ /g'`; do
    printf "\033[1;103;30m        $i\033[0m\n"
    ls "$i" | grep "ur_setup"
done
```

This will iterate through directories included in `PATH`, print them in yellow and then if there's something in there matching *ur_setup* pattern, print it. It can be done cleaner, but it's not worth creating a big function for a small need.

Also, if there's no result from `which ur_setup` (neither `not found` nor like `/usr/bin/spiderd`), you should try `type which`.